# SQL uses of "less than or equal to" <= vs. "not greater than" !> operators

Tags: sql, comparison-operators

- `<=` is [the *less than or equal to operator*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/less-than-or-equal-to-transact-sql).
- `!>` is [the *not greater than operator*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/not-greater-than-transact-sql).

Why are there two different comparison operators that seem to do the same thing.

Is there any situation where one would be prefered over the other?

Comment: Personally, I've NEVER seen `!>` used anywhere, in any language. Is that valid syntax somewhere?

Comment: No. When a RDBMS has both, they are equivalent.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276867(v=SQL.80).aspx

Comment: The `!=`, `!<` and `!>` are not standard if I remember well and are only supported by few systems.

Comment: +1 Looking at the msdn documentation for Sql server 2008r2 the operators do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<= and > are comparison operators, not logical operators. ! is a logical operator (means NOT). When you combine ! and >, you're simply inverting a comparison operator, so your end result is the same.

Having said that, <= is the common form, so I'd say it's preferred, for readability if nothing else. I don't know if there's a performance benefit to either, but I doubt it.

Edit:
Also, you didn't say which flavor of SQL you're dealing with. As @harryovers pointed out, that's a valid operator in MS-SQL, but it might not work everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

I can't see why you would use one over the other, but `!>` is not in ISO standards, and based on that I would say that `<=` is the preferred way.

Answer (score 3):

One reason to have the !> alternaive is to make it easy to put SQL inside XML. The less than sign introduces XML tags. If SQL with a < is included in either XML or HTML it would have to be escaped as &LT;. A greater than sign doesn't mean anything special unless it's been preceded by a less than sign.

Answer (score 2):

The `!=`, `!<` and `!>` are not standard comparison operators and are only supported by few systems, SQL-Server being one: **[msdn: Comparison Operators (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx)**. MySQL also supports `!=` but only that, not the other two.

The equivalent standard SQL comparison operators are `<>`, `>=` and `<=`.

In all situations, I would prefer the standard. You don't know when you have to migrate your code to another platform (and have less errors to deal with.)

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no difference. Only reason I can think of is to make it more human-readable in a certain context.

E.g. for the same reason I'd use `< 5` rather than `<= 4` if there was a significance to the **5** representing some limit in the context.

Answer (score 0):

When you say logical operators logical is `AND` and `OR` I've never seen !> I've seen `<>`

If you are referring to `!=` and `<>` they are the same.

Comment: Never used it...strange never knew that would even work.  Still it doesn't change how it works, just a different way to skin a cat I guess.